# Django. Школьный дневник. Расписание

Tags: django

Есть идея сделать онлайн-дневник для своей школы (Я из Молдавии, а у нас с технологиями трудно).
Но столкнулся с проблемой, как сделать расписание для каждого класса (Для каждого, потому что, например, у 10-ого нету некоторый предметов, в отличие от 5 и т.д), чтобы юзер с группой одного класса, не мог смотреть задания другого.

Я в Django первый раз, поэтому не разобрался целиком и полностью с models.py и фишками, которые в нем присутствуют.

Приму любые советы, предложения и камни в свою сторону)

[image: Непосредственно вывод предметов]

Comment: Ну по идее, проще всего сделать список групп через админку и добавить в каждую из них роли с разными правами доступа, то есть группа "6А класс"с пользователями админ препод(rwx), студент(r)

Comment: @Kramk, ок попробую. Спасибо.

Comment: Для того, что бы расписание было отдельно для каждого класса, нужно соответствующим образом выстроить модели базы данных. Здесь нужно понимать принципы реляционной теории и нормальной формы данных. То, что предлагает Kramk - плохое и небезопасное решение